# Can't get access token from Bigcommerce API, invalid client ID

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, bigcommerce

I am trying to get the access token so I can start building an app that works with BigCommerce. I've been following the docs here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/callback. I'm using the PHP client for Bigcommerce.

The response is HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request {"error":"Invalid client id."}.
I swear I'm using the correct client id and client secret! Or at least they are what is displayed when I click "View Client ID" on my draft app in the developer portal.

What on earth am I doing wrong?

```
$request = $_REQUEST;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Bigcommerce\Api\Connection;
$tokenUrl = "https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/token";
$connection = new Connection();
$connection->verifyPeer();
$connection->useUrlencoded();
$response = $connection->post($tokenUrl, array(
    "client_id" => "", //I won't type it here but it is correct
    "client_secret" => "", //also correct        
    "redirect_uri" => "https://127.0.0.1/project-custom/oauth.php", //this is the Auth Callback URL
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
    "code" => $request["code"], //when I echo these variables out they work
    "scope" => $request["scope"],
    "context" => $request["context"],
));  

print_r($connection->getLastError());
```

Comment: I see you have quotes for id,maybe remove them

Comment: Hmmm, no that didn't work. :( Removing them from the key gave me this notice: "Use of undefined constant client_id - assumed 'client_id'" and removing them from the value just caused a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!

I just removed the line `$connection->useUrlencoded();` because it needed to be sent as "Content-Type: application/json" and I was sending it as "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"